# how do I add the start menu thingy in latte dock?

Tags: kubuntu, latte-dock

[image: img]
there is no start menu. how do I fix this?

Comment: I don't have one running right now, but as far as I know, you right click in the dock somewhere and choose Add Widgets, then add an Applications Menu.

Comment: it works! thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: @Terrance

> I don't have one running right now, but as far as I know, you right click in the dock somewhere and choose Add Widgets, then add an Applications Menu